# usergrid set type column

Tags: cassandra, usergrid, apigee-baas

Is it possible to insert set type data (column) in usergrid ([as cassandra support set type column](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/use_set_t.html)). I tried

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:8080/<org>/<app>/<collection> 
                -d '{"name":"1974", "category":{"a","b","c"}}'
```

but it reply json_parse error.

---

Response to answer: I knew that payload in above request isn't valid JSON, I only tried to tell that is there any way I could make set type column (I need to prevent duplicate entries on single column record). with square brackets, It create list type column which don't prevent duplicate entries.

---

One of core member reply that on current Version (1.0), usergrid don't support set type column.

Answer (score 1):

It certainly is - but your payload isn't valid JSON; in JSON, you use square brackets to specify an Array: `[]`.

Try instead:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/<org>/<app>/<collection> 
            -d '{"name":"1974", "category":["a","b","c"]}'
#                                          ^           ^
```